# How to manipulate factor levels of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have in a data frame (Vitamin_C) one column (size) which only has two factor levels : "(1,20]" and "(20,35]". I want to change "(1,20]" to "reduce" and "(20,35]" to "normal".

I tried as follow:

```
Vitamin_C$size[Vitamin_C$size== "(1,20]"]<-c("Reduced")

Vitamin_C$size[Vitamin_C$size== "(20,35]"]<-c("Normal")
```

Error message:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, Vitamin_C$size == "(1,20]", value = c(NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: Note that you need to use backticks \`\`\` to denote code blocks, not normal quotes """.

Comment: Note `cut()` has a `labels` argument so the easiest thing is to label them at the time of creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R, use `factor()`:

```
Vitamin_C$size = factor(
  Vitamin_C$size,
  levels = c("(1,20]", "(20, 35]"),
  labels = c("Reduced", "Normal")
)
```

You could also directly modify the levels (make sure they start in the order you think they are!)

```
levels(Vitamin_C$size) = c("Reduced", "Normal")
```

As mentioned in comments, if you are creating this factor with `cut`, you can specify the labels you want directly in the `cut` command, which is best of all.

Comment: Thank you very much, using labels was perfect.